# Error when selecting between two dates from vb.net to sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the code below

```
technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand = "Select analyst as Analyst, sample_description, RFA_number, convert(varchar(10), updated_date, 103)as updated_date, customer, po_number, total_charged from New_Analysis_Data where analyst =  '" & FullName & "' and updated_date > '" & CDate(startdate.Text) & "'" & " and updated_date < '" & CDate(enddate.Text) & "'"
```

This basically passed through the sql command to the sql server and retrieves data between 2 dates.  These dates come from 2 text boxes (start and end date).  When I run this I get the error  - *The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

If I remove `& "'" & " and updated_date < '" & CDate(enddate.Text) & "'"` then it will work, seems to be an issue with the enddate.

Comment: The query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You're practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Apart from the sql-injection issue which is very serious and can be avoided easily with `sql-parameters`, what date-strings are you trying to convert to a datetime and what culture are you using(e.g. "en-us")? `CDate` uses the current culture to convert a string to `Date`.

Comment: culture is set to en-gb, I dont understand the difference ie why does it work if I remove enddate and just leave > startdate.  It displays everything greater than the date I enter.  As so as I add < enddate it throws the error

Comment: It's not the code change that fixes things, it's the data. The end date your are testing with does not convert to a datetime object correctly. It is possible your calendar extender is creating a US date that is invalid for the en-gb culture? ex: 5/24/2013 is correct in US, but invalid for en-gb.

Answer (score 4):

### Use query parameters!

```vb
technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand = _
      "SELECT analyst as Analyst, sample_description, RFA_number, " & _
            " convert(varchar(10), updated_date, 103)as updated_date, " & _ 
            " customer, po_number, total_charged " & _ 
      " FROM New_Analysis_Data " & _
      " WHERE analyst = @FullName " & _
            " AND updated_date >= @StartDate AND updated_date < @EndDate"

 With technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand.Parameters
      .Add("@FullName", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = FullName
      .Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startdate.Text
      .Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = enddate.Text
 End With
```

This also may or may not fix your problem with the end date. Even if it doesn't fix the problem, you should get a clearer error message... but most likely, you're not entering a valid date format in that textbox. Have you considered using a DatePicker control?

Comment: Great answer. I am beginner so I choose the way of beginner. You show path not only to user2050577 but also me. +1 for your giving us right direction.

Comment: I now get an error on technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand.Parameters says parameters is not a memeber of string

Comment: just for info I am using 2 textboxes combined with calender extenders

Answer (score 1):

1st off you should use `SqlParameters`!!!

It is much safer and you will also get rid of the date conversion issue.

```
            SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"
            Select  analyst as Analyst, 
                    sample_description,
                    RFA_number,
                    convert(varchar(10), updated_date, 103) as updated_date,
                    customer,
                    po_number,
                    total_charged
            from    New_Analysis_Data
            where   analyst =  @analyst
            and     updated_date between @startdate and @enddate";

            technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand = cmd;

            technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@analyst", FullName));
            technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@startdate",CDate(startdate.Text)));
            technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@enddate", CDate(enddate.Text)));
```

Comment: looks good but I now  get error on the `technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand = cmd` as it says value of technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand cannot be converted to a string

Comment: yes, you're right, then add the parameters to technician_sqlsource rather than the cmd

Answer (score 1):

If you want still in your old (unsafe) style .. you can try this ..

```
technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand = "Select analyst as Analyst, sample_description, RFA_number, convert(varchar(10), updated_date, 103)as updated_date, customer, po_number, total_charged from New_Analysis_Data where analyst =  '" & FullName & "' and updated_date > #" & startdate.Text & "# and updated_date < #" & enddate.Text & "#"
```

But later you must use query parameters! .. to prevent SQL Injection !

Comment: quick question - whats the # for

Comment: doesnt work for me Im afraid, get multiple errors to do with the date format.

Comment: nope, still get the original error..arrrggghhh, thanks for trying to help though

Comment: I use 2 textboxes with 2 ajax calender extenders

Comment: if you used VB datetimepicker .. I think my first try will work, but ajax calendar extender .. I don't know .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
technician_sqlsource.SelectCommand = "Select analyst as Analyst, sample_description, RFA_number, convert(varchar(10), updated_date, 103)as updated_date, customer, po_number, total_charged from New_Analysis_Data where analyst =  '" & FullName & "' and updated_date > '" & CDate(startdate.Text) & "' and updated_date < '" & CDate(enddate.Text) & "'"
```

Comment: @user2050577: You are getting the same error because the string is converted to date first, then the sql query is getting executed. But because the string is not a valid datetime the answer of ITBeginner doesn't solve your first problem. So first use sql-parameters, then solve your string-to-date conversion issue(you haven't shown examples), then use the corect sql which is also easier when you don't concatenate strings to a sql query but use parameters.